# Simple Java code gets "Could not find or load main class JavaBatchInserter.class"

Tags: java

I have:

```
public class JavaBatchInserter {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

I go to the `pwd` where my file, named `JavaBatchInserter.java`, is located and run:

```
java JavaBatchInserter.java
```

and get:

> Could not find or load main class JavaBatchInserter.java

It's the simplest thing and I can't make it work. ): Help please! Thanks!

Note: I don't want to create a project and a bunch of directories if possible.

Comment: `java JavaBatchInserter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, compile *the file* `JavaBatchInserter.java`

```
javac JavaBatchInserter.java
```

Then give *your full class name* to JVM for execution

```
java JavaBatchInserter
```

Answer (score 3):

You run the command **java JavaBatchInserter.java**

It is wrong.First compile the class by running **javac JavaBatchInserter.java**

The try to run by **java JavaBatchInserter**